# reading XML node that has sentance eding with (".")

Tags: c#, xml

I am reading from xml file in c#. I am able to read attributes and values but I came across this

```
<aims><![CDATA[Compare and contrast the structure, function and features of different cell types, including prokaryotic and eukaryotic cells, and plant and animal cells.
Describe evolutionary relationships between prokaryotic and eukaryotic cells.
Explain mitosis & meiosis & relationships between cell division & genetic variability.
Explain how plants use sunlight to generate energy in photosynthesis.
Describe relationships & interactions between cells in the tissues of plants & animals.
Apply appropriate scientific principles.
Analyse, present, evaluate and interpret scientific data from a wide variety of sources.]]></aims>
```

This node has lot of information to read from. I want to read each sentence ending with (".") as a value like this
1- Compare and contrast the structure, function and features of different cell types, including prokaryotic and eukaryotic cells, and plant and animal cells.
2- Describe evolutionary relationships between prokaryotic and eukaryotic cells.
and so on

ok i am trying to loop inside this node . Is there any way to loop inside the this prticular node?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the actual XML and to know what you have tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, this whole text is in a text element. Once you have it as one big string, use `value.Split(".")` to split by sentences.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sentences = XDocument.Load(fName)
                .Descendants("aims")
                .First().Value
                .Split(".".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select((line,i) => (i+1) + "- " + line.Trim())
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following

```
String data= //Read from the required XML tag
String[] sentences=data.Split('.');
```

Comment: string LoName = xmlo.Value;//Read from the required XML tag string[] sentences= LoName.Split('.');  if (lo.Name.EndsWith(x))
                        {
                            tnLO.Nodes.Add("LO " + " name: " + lo.Name + " Verb: " + lo.VerbName + " bloom level: " + "(" + lo.Bloom + ")");
                        }

Comment: sorry ignore what i comment

Comment: ok i am trying to loop inside this node . Is there any way to loop inside the this prticular node?

Comment: what do you mean by "loop inside a node"? . Please explain clearly.